# Is it possible to backup some files before user uninstall FMX Delphi android app?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, uninstallation

Is there any way to get the backup of some files which resides inside the app folder in Android before user uninstall the FMX Delphi app?

Thanks

Comment: There is no onBeforeDeinstallListener for Android apps.

Comment: Look a hasFragileUserData attribute for application tag in manifest file

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't ask me if I want to keep the data despite hasFragileUserData="true" in AndroidManifes.xml

Comment: Maybe it depends on Android version.

Comment: The flag was new in Android 10 - see https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/06/random-musings-q-beta-4.html

Answer (score 1):

You can save necessary data after any change on your app to external storage or another location instead of application path  and prevent remove of that data by uninstalling app and after reinstall of the app, restore that.